# Can I keep the laptop lid open all the time?

Tags: laptop, display, external-display

I have a laptop which I use as my main computer at home and I rarely take it with me. My setup is a dual monitor system, I have a main monitor and I also use the laptop screen as a second monitor.

Since I don't move it I keep the laptop lid always open. Is it okay if I don't close it at all, not even when it's turned off? It seems OK, but I wonder if the lid hinges are designed to hold the weight of the open monitor all the time.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are more than capable of constantly holding it open, it's actually probably better that way. The more you move the lid, the more wear you apply to the hinges over time. Just ensure you clean the laptop every once in a while, if dirt builds up and it is hard to close, you may damage it trying to force it closed. Keeping it open allows dust to get into the speakers easier as well if they are the type built around the keyboard.

Comment: Also, most laptops ventilate better when open, keeping them cooler.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops are not designed to be open for a long time. I have two laptops already and used them for a long time without closing the lid. Both of them have damage on the hinge. Close your laptop when you are not using it especially if some parts of the body or the body is made of plastic.